# Dedicated server with ssd best practice

Tags: centos, ssd

I am getting new dedicated server with 240gb ssd drive and 2 x 3tb hdd.

I am thinking to put OS on ssd, and then mount uploads dir in my HOME/USER/ directory to HDD.

Or maybe vice versa?

What is this best solution to fully take advantage of ssd disk, and how can i do it?

Comment: You put the stuff on the SSD that really needs to be fast. What exactly that is, only you know that, because you didn't tell us what's going to run on the server!

Comment: How many SSDs do you have?

Comment: I have one ssd on my server.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote in comments, you have only one ssd. This is very limiting factor for usage. You should use it only for data you can loose anytime, probably only some caches (you can use it as filesystem cache).

If you want to use SSD for storing important data (databases, scripts, depends on what are you using your server for), you need at least 2 SSDs in mirror (raid-1) configuration to prevent data loose when SSD fails (and it will fail).